# WordPress Docker over NGINX SSL reverse proxy doesn't work as expected

Tags: wordpress, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

When I use NGINX to create a reverse proxy for a WordPress Docker container, WordPress specifies `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)` to be `https://hiddenurl.com:443`. So all my links contain the port 443, and if I delete this port, the website is no longer accessible due to an infinite redirect loop.

I have entered in the `wp-config.php` that SSL should be activated via `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';`.

NGINX Config:

```
    location ~ /(?<wppath>.*) {
        rewrite ^/(.*) /$1 break;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7676/$wppath$is_args$args;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-forwarded protocol https;
        proxy_set_header upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade
    }
```

This causes the domain `hiddenurl.com` to work, but `hiddenurl.com/about` does redirect to `127.0.0.1/about`.

The redirect seems to come from WordPress:
[image: Response Headers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using this as an nginx config:

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:7676;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

      }
```

And append this to the top of `wp-config.php`

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = '1';

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had a WordPress 301 redirect loop using the WordPress container serving over port 80 behind an nginx reverse proxy with the following configuration:

```
server {
    # SSL configuration
    #
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name   _______.com.au   www._______.com.au;
    proxy_redirect off;
    
    location / {                      
            proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.0:6080/;
            
    }


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/_______.com.au/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/_______.com.au/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www._______.com.au) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = _______.com.au) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;

    server_name   _______.com.au   www._______.com.au;
    return 301 https://_______.com.au$request_uri;
}
```

My wp_config.php was using the default configuration generated by Official WordPress Docker container. The problem occurred in the canonical.php function because of this line in the nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
```

When the url is passed into the canonical.php function a 301 redirect loop was setup because `https://______.com.au:443` was different from `https://______.com.au`. Removing `$server_port` fixed the problem for me:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

I hope that my time consuming investigation saves someone some time!